# Create New Users using JIRA REST API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to create new users using JIRA REST API. However the post method syntax description is empty when I am checking the [REST documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e5274). Does anyone know the JSON syntax and the REST handle for creating new users?

Answer (score 2):

The JSON Object to use is:

```
{ 
"name":"username",
"password":"****",
"emailAddress":"username@local",
"displayName":"user name",
"notification":"false" 
}
```

Comment: This one works perfectly. The REST handle is /rest/api/2/user. Thanks for the help.
Do you know any way of deactivating the added user via REST. I tried a PUT to change the "active":true to "active":false. But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

The user creation via REST for JIRA installed version or on-demand version is available using the rest handle

> /rest/api/2/user

A POST call should be made with the the following values in the header

> Content-Type:application/json
>
> Authentication:Simple username:password

**Note: The Username:Password in the authentication header should be encoded in base64 format**

The JSON to post is as follows

```
{
    "name": "<Username>",
    "password": "<Password>",
    "emailAddress": "<Email Address>",
    "displayName": "<Display Name>"
}
```

***The users will be created in jira-users group and the will be active. The active status cannot be changed while creation or after creation using a PUT call. This is a major constraint.***

Answer (score 0):

I would try calling a GET service for the `user` resource and use the same jSon object structure to POST creation of a new user.

Comment: Answer by LukeSolar works fine. Thanks for the response

Comment: I've tried to give a general answer on how to get the definition of a jSon resource that may be helpful in other cases, not only in this specific case.