# Ansible to create an user in JIRA

Tags: ansible, jira

I need to create a user in jira by using Ansible.YAML file

When I read the documents about [Ansible-jira](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/jira_module.html), there is no documentation present on the creation of the user in jira. Only how to create an issue is present (which I am not looking for)

So is there any way that I can create a jira user by writing ansible YAML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jira module is unfortunately limited to adding or modifying issues.

To work around this you could use the Jira rest api in combination with the uri module (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/uri_module.html). You should check if the payload ([Create New Users using JIRA REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609725/create-new-users-using-jira-rest-api)) matches your version:

```
- name: Create a JIRA issue
  uri:
    url: https://your.jira.example.com/rest/api/2/user
    method: POST
    user: your_username
    password: your_pass
    body: '{"name":"username","password":"****","emailAddress":"username@local","displayName":"user name","notification":"false"}'
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 201
    body_format: json
```